# Ways to implement data integrity measures on static and non static data

Tags: integrity

I would like to know is there a need to implement data integrity measure given the scenario?

Clients send data/files (may or may not contain public keys) to the server via server side CA cert. The data/files may be static or continuous changing.

The data that rarely change in my case will be something like emails or similar identities such as user ID from messenger such as Session messenger and ATox or QTox p2p messenger. The same can be said to the system generated user ID.

Continuous changing data refers to something like user submitted public keys or passwords. Since these data will change without notice by users/clients and also malicious insider/outsider, it's not possible to use cryptography hashing and regular backups to address on data availability and integrity.

If there's a need to implement data integrity measures on the provider side, is there any common methods to apply data integrity measures on these 2 types of data which are static and continuous changing?

One of the ways that I know for implementing data integrity measures on static data is using cryptographic hashing and routine backup.

Comment: if possible please add some more detail about your use-case .. what do you mean by continuous changing .. continuous append, eg a log file? do you want to assert the integrity of the change only? data at a point in time? etc.

Comment: I slightly edited, is this clearer or need more statements?